# Match paths of node types where nodes may have cycles

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find a match pattern to match paths of certain node types. I don't care about the type of relation. Any relation type may match. I only care about the node types.

Of course the following would work:

```
MATCH (n)-->(:a)-->(:b)-->(:c) WHERE id(n) = 0
```

But, some of these paths may have relations to themselves. This could be for `:b`, so I'd also like to match:

```
MATCH (n)-->(:a)-->(:b)-->(:b)-->(:c) WHERE id(n) = 0
```

And:

```
MATCH (n)-->(:a)-->(:b)-->(:b)-->(:b)-->(:c) WHERE id(n) = 0
```

I can do this with relations easily enough, but I can't figure out how to do this with nodes, something like:

```
MATCH (n)-->(:a)-->(:b*1..)-->(:c) WHERE id(n) = 0
```

As a practical example, let's say I have a database with people, cars and bikes. The cars and bikes are "owned" by people, and people have relationships like son, daughter, husband, wife, etc. What I'm looking for is a query that from a specific node, gets all nodes of related types. So:

```
MATCH (n)-->(:person*1..)-->(:car) WHERE Id(n) = 0
```

I would expect that to get node "n", it's parents, grandparents, children, grandchildren, all recursively. And then of those people, their cars. If I could assume that I know the full list of relations, and that they only apply to people, I could get this to work as follows:

```
MATCH
  p = (n)-->(:person)-[:son|daughter|husband|wife|etc*0..]->(:person)-->(:car)
WHERE Id(n) = 0
RETURN nodes(p)
```

What I'm looking for is the same without having to specify the full list of relations; but just the node label.

Comment: Does it matter how many relationships (:b) has with itself?

Comment: I updated the question with a practical example. I assume that :b is self referencing in the schema, not the nodes itself. In the case of people, I want to pull in a full extended family in one query.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

If you want to find the path from one Person node to each Car node, using only the node labels, and assuming nodes may create cycles, you can use apoc.path.expandConfig.

For example:

```
MERGE (mark:Person {name: "Mark"})
MERGE (lju:Person {name: "Lju"})
MERGE (praveena:Person {name: "Praveena"})
MERGE (zhen:Person {name: "Zhen"})
MERGE (martin:Person {name: "Martin"})
MERGE (joe:Person {name: "Joe"})
MERGE (stefan:Person {name: "Stefan"})
MERGE (alicia:Person {name: "Alicia"})

MERGE (markCar:Car {name: "Mark's car"})
MERGE (ljuCar:Car {name: "Lju's car"})
MERGE (praveenaCar:Car {name: "Praveena's car"})
MERGE (zhenCar:Car {name: "Zhen's car"})

MERGE (zhen)-[:CHILD_OF]-(mark)
MERGE (praveena)-[:CHILD_OF]-(martin)
MERGE (praveena)-[:MARRIED_TO]-(joe)
MERGE (zhen)-[:CHILD_OF]-(joe)
MERGE (alicia)-[:CHILD_OF]-(joe)
MERGE (zhen)-[:CHILD_OF]-(mark)
MERGE (anthony)-[:CHILD_OF]-(rik)
MERGE (martin)-[:CHILD_OF]-(mark)
MERGE (stefan)-[:CHILD_OF]-(zhen)
MERGE (lju)-[:CHILD_OF]-(stefan)

MERGE (markCar)-[:OWNED]-(mark)
MERGE (ljuCar)-[:OWNED]-(lju)
MERGE (praveenaCar)-[:OWNED]-(praveena)
MERGE (zhenCar)-[:OWNED]-(zhen)
```

Running a query:

```
MATCH (n:Person{name:'Joe'}) 
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(n, {labelFilter: "Person|/Car", uniqueness: "NODE_GLOBAL"})
YIELD path
RETURN path
```

will return four unique paths from Joe node to the four car nodes. There are several options for uniqueness of the path, see [`uniqueness`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.subgraphAll/)

The `/CAR` makes it a Termination label, i.e. returned paths are only up to this given label.